# ASP.NET - Detect Changed Values in a Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, repeater

Good Morning,

I have a page with a Repeater.  The Repeater typically contains 250 - 500 rows.

The ItemTemplate contains 5 TextBox controls and 1 DropDownList.  The user can modify any of these values.

After modifying one or more values (in one or more rows) the user will click the 'Save' button.  At this point I want to update the database -- but first I need to identify the rows that have changed.

I've experimented with the TextBox.TextChange event ... but I have 5 TextBox controls per row ... I don't want to update the same item five times ... so I am looking for something better.

It would be great if there was a RepeaterItem.SomeValueChanged event ... but so far I haven't found one! :-)

Anyone have a more 'elegant' solution?

Thank you!

Glen

Comment: If you use the `GridView` instead of the `Repeater` control that is included by default...

Comment: @balexandre, are you sure about this?

Comment: @balexandre -- I'm sure there are other (perhaps better) ways to achieve this (and in the future we may try the DataGridView) but right now I am looking for a way to achieve this using a Repeater.  Thanks!

Comment: @Glen, are you happy with hidden fields which stores the original values? you have to store the original values in some way and then compare with the new values from the inputs

Comment: @Adrian -- That's exactly what I am doing now:

foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in rptListItems.Items)
{
 TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)rptItm.FindControl("txtQuantity");
        HiddenField hidQuantity = (HiddenField)rptItm.FindControl("hidQuantity");
        if (string.Compare(txtQuantity.Text.Trim(), hidQuantity.Value.Trim(), true) != 0)
 {
  // value has changed

Comment: @Adrian -- Guess I was just wondering if there is a more 'elegant' (more efficient) way of doing this?

Comment: which .Net version are you using?

Comment: @Adrian -- I'm embarrassed to say that we're still using 2.0.

Comment: no problem, I will delete my answer; still I think you can use the idea to use a single hidden field to store the original values.

Comment: @Adrian Iftode - I don't think LINQ is an option since we're still using .NET 2.0.  (I've read about hacks to get LINQ working on 2.0 but we don't have the time/resources right now for something like that)  At this point, it looks like Hidden fields might be my best option.

Comment: @Adrian Iftode - I think I can safely disable ViewState on my Hidden fields -- so a single Hidden field wouldn't make my ViewState any smaller.  I guess calling RepeaterItem.FindControl once (instead of five times) would offer some advantage ... but it would be somewhat offset by serializing/deserializing the value(s), don't you think?  Using Hidden fields this way 'feels' like I am back to writing ASP Classic in VBScript! :-)

Comment: Agree, but LINQ was used for other thing, really it doesn't make much difference between LINQ and using foreach blocks in this case, just some extra lines in the second case. My answer was still based on hidden fields. Now I'm thinking on using a single hidden field to  store the original values and on a simple mechanism to compare the inputs (tb,ddl,cb) and this hidden field. You can a policy like each input contains the Column name and use this at the FindControl method..

Comment: @Adrian Iftode - I am going to stick with what I have for now -- mostly because I am very short on time and need to finish this project quickly.  Hopefully we'll be making the move to .NET 4.0 soon and I will dive into LINQ!  Thanks for your help!!  I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a hidden field to reflect a value which would tell you that something has changed. On initial databinding set its value to 0. Wire some js for the textboxes such that they'll update the hiddenfield with 1. Then on the btn save event you need only be interested only in those items that has 1.

Comment: I actually need to compare the BEFORE and AFTER values for each control (TextBox/DropDownList) ... so this isn't going to work for me.  However, I didn't clearly state that in the original question (I should have) and I think that what you're suggesting makes good sense, so I am marking your suggestion as the 'accepted' answer.  Thank you for taking the time to read my question and offer a solution!

Comment: it may be a bad idea, but u cn store List<T> in the viewstate. Class T should be marked as serializable